# NSURLErrorDomain Arbitrary scheme not working on ios webview (react-native-webview)

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

This error is occurring using react-native-webview but I dont know if it relates to that library or ios webview itself and/or my configuration (Info.plist etc.)

I have a link with a custom scheme "swish://" that would normally open the Swish application. However on iOS I get NSURLErrorDomain, error code -1002 "unsupported URL"

Ive added the url to Info.plist under

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>swish</string>
</array>
```

Ive added originWhiteList={['swish://*', 'https://*']} to the WebView

Strange thing is onNavigationStateChange from the webview logs

```
LOG  {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "loading": true, "navigationType": "other", "target": 1909, "title": "", "url": "about:blank"}
LOG  {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "loading": false, "target": 1909, "title": "", "url": "about:blank"}
LOG  {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "loading": false, "navigationType": "click", "target": 1909, "title": "", "url": "swish://asd?b=c"}
```

and then it fails with

```
Encountered an error loading page {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "code": -1002, "description": "unsupported URL", "didFailProvisionalNavigation": true, "domain": "NSURLErrorDomain", "loading": false, "target": 1909, "title": "", "url": "about:blank"}
```

so it is complaining about 'about:blank' ... I have no idea how to get around this. Entering "swish://" into safari opens the application as expected.

the html is basically

`<a href='swish://asd?b=c'>SWISHhHH</a>` (ive tried with various changes to that link to test if something else is wrong)

Anyone have any clue what Im missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a WebView that opened BankID. You can intercept all requests and handle your specific uri scheme yourself using the prop `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`

See my example:

```
<WebView
  source={{
    uri: 'https://login.example.com/...',
   }}
   originWhitelist={['https://*', 'bankid://*']}
   onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(r) => {
   if (r.url.startsWith('bankid:///')) {
     Linking.openURL(r.url)
     return false
   }
   return true
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add [UrlSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app) in Xcode from this link, this should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change the uri domain :

Please use  "Https" instead of "Http"